# Tab focus not working with ion-label for accessibility

Tags: html, ionic3, accessibility, semantic-ui, tabindex

I am trying to implement accessibility in my Ionic web app, but keyboard tab focusing is not working with `ion-label` and unable to read the label by screen-reader. below is the `HTML` for the label:

```html
<div padding-bottom="" padding-top="" text-center="">
   <ion-chip navpush="HelpPage" class="chip chip-md">
       <ion-label class="md-help-text label label-md">Forgot Your Password?</ion-label>
   </ion-chip>
</div>
```

When I use the keyboard Tab button, focus jumps over this element and goes to the next element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above by `Graham Ritchie`, labels are not focusable by default. Hence we can use the help of the `ARIA: button` role with `tabIndex`.

If using `role="button"` instead of the semantic `<button> or <input type="button">` elements like `label`, it will make an element appear as a button control to a screen-reader and for getting the focus we need to use `tabIndex`.

```
<div text-center padding-bottom padding-top >
        <ion-chip class="chip chip-md" navPush="HelpPage"  [navParams]="account">
            <ion-label tabindex="0" role="button" class="md-help-text label label-md" >Forgot Your Password?</ion-label>
        </ion-chip>
    </div>
```

Reference links : [ARIA Role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role)
[TabIndex Info](https://bitsofco.de/how-and-when-to-use-the-tabindex-attribute/)

> Note: Above code works for me for keyboard tab focus access as well as for screen-reader.

Answer (score 1):

`labels` are not focusable by default.

`<a>` or `<button>` elements should be used instead (I do not know the ionic way of doing that).

Use a `<button>` if the desired action is to stay on the same page.

Use a `<a>` if you are navigating to a different page.

The only other option you have (this is a **last** resort as given the above mark-up it doesn't seem necessary) is to use a `tabindex=0` on the clickable element.

This will make the element focusable within the tab order of the page (do not use a positive integer for your `tabindex` as that breaks tab order).

Comment: The problem is it's very hard to tell the underlying semantics of `ion-chip` and `ion-label`. If `ion-label` is 'really' a label, then it's a label `for` something operable (presumably the chip, whatever that is).